# Django - Redirect to a subclass admin page

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, inheritance, python-requests

I'm creating a web application with Django.

In my models.py I have a class BaseProduct and a class DetailProduct, which extends BaseProduct.

In my admin.py I have BaseProductAdmin class and DetailProductAdmin class, which extends BaseProductAdmin.

I have another class called System, with a many to many relation with BaseProduct.

In the System admin page, I can visualize a list of the BaseProduct objects related to that system.

When I click on a product, the application redirect me to the BaseProduct admin page.

When a product of the list is a DetailProduct object, I would like to be redirected on the DetailProduct admin page instead.

Any idea on how to do this?

In models.py :

```
class BaseProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
   _prod_type_id = models.ForeignKey(
    ProductTypes, verbose_name="product type", db_column='_prod_type_ID')  
    systems = models.ManyToManyField(
    'database.System', through='database.SystemProduct')

    def connected_to_system(self):
        return self.systems.exists()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'products'
        verbose_name = "Product"
        ordering = ['id', ]


class System(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def has_related_products(self):
        """ Returns True if the system is connected with products. """
        return self.products_set.exists()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = u'systems'
        verbose_name = "System"
        ordering = ['id', ]


class DetailProduct(BaseProduct):
    options_id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    product = models.OneToOneField(BaseProduct, db_column='_product_ID',    parent_link=True)
    min_height = models.FloatField(help_text="Minimum height in meters.")
    max_height = models.FloatField(help_text="Maximum height in meters.")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetailProduct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.pk:
            self._prod_type_id = ProductTypes.objects.get(pk=9)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'detail_product'
        verbose_name = "Detail product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Detail products"


class SystemProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
    _system_id = models.ForeignKey(System, db_column='_system_ID')
    _product_id = models.ForeignKey(BaseProduct, db_column='_Product_ID')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'system_product'
        unique_together = ('_system_id', '_product_id')
        verbose_name = "system/product connection"
```

In my admin.py page:

```
class SystemProductInlineGeneric(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SystemProduct
    extra = 0
    show_edit_link = True
    show_url = True


class SystemProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SystemProduct
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Remove the blank option for the inlines. If the user wants to remove
        the inline should use the proper delete button. In this way we can
        safely check for orphan entries. """

        super(SystemProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        modelchoicefields = [field for field_name, field in self.fields.iteritems() if
                         isinstance(field, forms.ModelChoiceField)]

        for field in modelchoicefields:
            field.empty_label = None


class SystemProductInlineForSystem(SystemProductInlineGeneric):
        """ Custom inline, used under the System change page. Prevents all product-system
        connections to be deleted from a product. """
        form = SystemProductForm
        raw_id_fields = ("_product_id",)

class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SystemProductInlineForSystem]
    actions = None
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    fieldsets = [('System information', 
         {'fields': (('id', 'name',), ),}),
    ]
    list_display_links = ('id', 'configuration',)
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

    save_as = True
```

Comment: Please post your models definition and the code that displays the "list of BaseProducts" in your Channel admin page.

Comment: I posted the code. In the previous message I made a mistake, the name of the other object is System instead of Channel, as you can see.

Comment: I don't see where the "list of BaseProducts" is generated... Did you override the admin template for SystemAdmin ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm using the default template

Comment: Uhu sorry I didn't spot the `SystemProduct` was the many2many "through" model.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is how to change the InlineAdmin (`SystemProductInlineForSystem`) template so the "change link" redirects to the `DetailProduct` admin change form (instead of the `BaseProduct` admin change form) when the product is actually a `DetailProduct`.

I never had to deal with this use case so I can't provide a full-blown definitive answer, but basically you will have to [override the inlineadmin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) for `SystemProductInlineForSystem` and change [the part of the code that generates this url](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.6/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html#L34).

I can't tell you exactly which change you will have to make (well, I probably could if I had a couple hours to spend on this but that's not the case so...), so you will have to analyze this part of the code and find out by yourself - unless of course someone more knowledgeable chimes in...